# Recursive template

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

Is it possible to write template definition for this data type?

```
myclass<int, myclass<int> > data;
```

Second template variable should be optional with default value of the same type.

**Clarification**

Now I use this definition:

```
class defaultClass { };
template <typename T, typename C=defaultClass>
class myclass { ... };
```

I'd like to predefine that `defaultClass` is `myclass<T>`

I'd like to implement something like auto implemented properties: the second parameter should be context in which the wrapped variable is defined. If the context is ommited, it should be in the object created by the template class itself. (I realize it could be solved another way, this is just use case.)

Comment: "default value of the same type" --- which type?

Comment: If `defaultClass` is `myclass<T>`, that thing can only expand to `myclass<T, myclass<T, myclass<T, myclass<T, myclass<T, myclass<T, …>>>>>>`

Comment: @KennyTM: I realize that and I hope it is possible to stop the recursion after the first step, i.e. to create `myclass<int, myclass1<int> >`, where `myclass1` is somehow alias or derived from `myclass` or something like this.

Comment: why make things confusing if simple solutions (CRTP) exist?

Comment: @Walter: I just discovered it, thanks to Viktor Latypov response. However I can't seem to get it work if the `derived` is also template (seem my comment to his answer). Could you clarify it?

Comment: I've clarified things a little - you just have to pass the template arguments of the derived class. So, the "CRTP" always "works" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very similar to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

You can do the thing you want by making a class hierarchy with template base type and then each of your classes may be derived from that base like

```
template<class T> class base { ... };

class derived: public base<derived> {...};
```

Comment: you can do the "template<typename T> class myclass1: public myclass<T, myclass1<T> > {...} " here. You have to "pass" the template arguments to match the definition of the class.